# Keyboard shortcut in OpenOffice to incrementally increase or decrease font size?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, openoffice, openoffice-writer

Is there a keyboard shortcut in OpenOffice Writer that will allow me to incrementally change the font size?

If I'm switching between 12 and 14 and 16 often, it would be much easier to be able to tap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> a of couple times to go from 12 to 14. The function I'm looking for would be similar to Firefox's zoom feature.

Comment: http://www.superuser.com

Comment: not programming related. Anyway, go tools->customize->keyboard, there you can associate shortcuts to various functions.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Tools -> Customize -> Keyboard.

Choose "Format" from the column on bottom-left called "Category".

Choose "Increase Font" & "Reduce Font" from the bottom-middle column called "Function".

(Note that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> is broken; you can't use the normal keyboard plus, you need to use the numpad plus, or another keyboard shortcut.)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>.

Comment: This does not work for me. Perhaps because OpenOffice writer politically does not have the functionality to increment/decrement the sizes, http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=85002. I wonder how you manage your hotkeys to call non-existing functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Althought not by default, you can assign a keyboard shortcut to this function.

Go to Tools Menu -> Customize -> Keyboard

Comment: And? What is next? Why do you answer only one half of the question?

Answer (score -1):

Nov 2015 Openoffice Writer 4.1.2
 "IN THEORY" you can create custom keyboard shortcuts as suggested above, but they don't work, certainly not like MS-Word. *(a number of reasons have been suggested as to why, but that's irrelevant)*
HOWEVER, you can customize the FORMATTING TOOLBAR, and put the Increase/Reduce Font Size buttons on the toolbar, which is what I do in Excel
 (View -> Toolbars-> Customize: and those two buttons are not selected by default)
For me, this is now working like it does in MS Office

Comment: A quicker way to achieve this: click the dropdown caret to the right of the menu, and go to `Visible Buttons -> Increase Font` or whichever you want to add to the toolbar. You can also remove this way.